# Check browser CSS property support with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, browser-feature-detection

Is it possible in JavaScript to know if a CSS property is supported by the client browser? I'm talking about the rotation properties of CSS3. I want to execute some functions only if the browser supports them.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I believe you can do it this way:

```
if ('WebkitTransform' in document.body.style 
 || 'MozTransform' in document.body.style 
 || 'OTransform' in document.body.style 
 || 'transform' in document.body.style) 
{
    alert('I can Rotate!');
}
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that this technically tests whether the browser supports the CSS3 `transform` style and not specifically the `rotate()` [transform function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#CSS_transform_functions). In my (limited) experience, the former has always implied the latter, but I’m not sure if that’s a reliable assumption (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528176/do-all-browsers-that-support-css3-transforms-also-support-all-transform-function)).

Comment: Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dp3ueaz5/
But I would rather use this function: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-detect-css-support-in-browsers-with-javascript--net-16444
Better to understand and it automatically checks vendor prefixes. ;)

Answer (score 8):

There is a new DOM API [CSS.supports](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-conditional/#the-css-interface) for that purpose. FF, Opera (as supportsCSS) and Chrome Canary already implement this method.

For cross-browser compatibility you can use my [CSS.supports polyfill](https://github.com/termi/CSS.supports/)

Example:

```
CSS.supports("display", "table");//IE<8 return false
```

But, you still need to specify browser prefix for prefixing css properties. For example:

```
CSS.supports("-webkit-filter", "blur(10px)");
```

I suggest to using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) for feature-detection.

Answer (score 1):

May be try this?

```
var temp = document.createElement('div');
var isSupport = temp.style['propName'] != undefined;
```

Comment: Not an ideal answer, but why is this downvoted? I don't see any technical error with it

Comment: @RobertDundon perhaps my solution is like the first, anyway thanks for support =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) library.

Example for css transform:

in .css file;

```
.no-csstransforms .box { color: red; }
.csstransforms .box { color: green; }
```

in .js file;

```
if (Modernizr.csstransforms) {
  // supported
} else {
  // not-supported
}
```