# Css property support detection

Tags: javascript

Is there a **generic** way in javascript to check if the css property is supported by current browser or not?

I am currently using "**document.compatMode**" to check if it is quirks or not. But there must be a way to check specific to a property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [check browser css property support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342994/check-browser-css-property-support)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this, ex:

```
typeof document.body.style.borderRadius
```

In supported browsers, it should return 'string'. In non supported, it will be 'undefined'

Comment: Thanks, it works. Anyways do you know a way to find pseudo class is also supported or not? I meant by ':hover',':active'.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new DOM API [CSS.supports](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-conditional/#CSS-interface) for that purpose. FF, Opera (as supportsCSS) and Chrome Canary already implement this method.

For cross-browser compatibility you can use my [CSS.supports polyfill](https://github.com/termi/CSS.supports/)

Example:

`CSS.supports("display", "table");//IE<8 return false`

But, you still need to specify browser prefix for prefixing css properties. For example:

`CSS.supports("-webkit-filter", "blur(10px)");`

I suggest to using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) for feature-detection.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am familiar with Modernizr but didn't want to include a js lib for 1 single detection.

Answer (score -3):

No.

There's not.

Comment: There is never "no" for a problem.