# Detect browser support to css property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect if the user's browser supports a certain css property. Is this possible using jQuery? I searched for the jQuery support() but it didn't do what I wanted.

Comment: [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: I'll be simpler if you keep a dictionary yourself of feature support.

Comment: possible duplicate of [check browser css property support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342994/check-browser-css-property-support)

Answer (score 1):

Just check out this framework, it is widely used by several sites.
http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Here is a list of the CSS features that modernizr can detect: http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-css

Comment: I like it *widely used by several sites* :) really telling something