# How to check if css3 is not supported by browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I test the browser that css3 is supported or not?

```
if(!css3){
//if at least one css3 feature isn't supported
//do stuff here
}
```

Comment: This might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/q/1342994/1696560

Comment: http://modernizr.com/

Comment: you won't be able to, But you can try [`modernizr`](http://www.modernizr.com/)

Comment: CSS3 is not really something you can test for all at once. Write appropriate CSS. Write appropriate fallbacks. JavaScript-based detection of anything just kind of ends in sadness.

Comment: CSS3 is not a single 'thing' that browsers implement, it's a collection of standards, I don't think *any* browser *fully* implements CSS3; only parts of it. You want to test for the parts you're using.

Comment: This might help http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-css3-property-browser-support/

Answer (score 1):

Try to assign a CSS3 property (that's relevant to what you're doing - no sense testing `transition` if you're actually just doing `transform`), andthen immediately check to see if the value "stuck". If the browser supports what you gave it, it will stick. Otherwise, it will change back to an empty string.

Comment: & have to check for vender prefixing also; eg: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

Answer (score 1):

No browser supports all the features of CSS3 but some of the features are supported by browsers.

You may check this:-

- [Quick Tip: Detect CSS3 Support in Browsers with JavaScript](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-detect-css3-support-in-browsers-with-javascript--net-16444)
- [How to Detect Browser Support for CSS3 Properties](http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-css3-property-browser-support/)

> We now have HTML5 and CSS3. No browser supports every feature so it’s
>   often necessary to include shims or use detection techniques to ensure
>   cross-browser compatibility

Comment: Personally, I generally don't bother with vendor prefixes. Most of the time, CSS3 features are eye candy, and therefore browser support is not essential. Does it really matter if users of IE8 get square borders instead of rounded ones?