# Do all browsers that support CSS3 transforms also support all transform functions?

Tags: css, cross-browser, transform

I haven't found a case in which a browser supports one [CSS3 transform function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#CSS_transform_functions) and not another, but I haven't been able to find confirmation that all browsers in relatively common use follow this pattern.

For example, if a browser supports `transform: scale()`, is it safe to assume it also supports `transform: rotate()`? (This question applies to all prefixed versions too, ie. if `-webkit-transform: scale()` is supported, is `-webkit-transform: rotate()` guaranteed to work?)

Another way to phrase it: is the alert in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6924859/3508398) (copied below) guaranteed to be true?

```
if ('WebkitTransform' in document.body.style 
 || 'MozTransform' in document.body.style 
 || 'OTransform' in document.body.style 
 || 'transform' in document.body.style) 
{
    alert('I can Rotate!');
}
```

Comment: At this point it is not safe to assume anything of this kind. Even if a browser theoretically supports what you need, there might be some known issues regarding specifics of some CSS3 rules behaviour. I would suggest checking browser compatibility at any time and testing. That is the only assurence.

Comment: My question isn’t necessarily whether all browsers implement all transform functions correctly or in the same way, but rather if any browsers have specifically chosen to implement certain transform functions and not others. In other words, is the code above a reliable check that the browser will “try” to rotate things?

Comment: If Transforms level 2 adds new functions to the spec - assuming there will be a level 2 spec after the [current one](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1) matures - then the answer to this will be a straight no.